# Conjunction: al ver todavía

Tags: conjunciones

This one has kind of flumoxed me...
I have found the following sentence and can't work out what 'al ver' means in this context. Google and wordreference haven't thrown any light. Any ideas?

> Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren *al ver* todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios que en muchos casos están reflejando gracias a la llegada de las nuevas marcas a varias rutas como...

Comment: Por favor, podrías escribir el texto completo al párrafo correspondiente con sus correspondientes comas? Pues en realidad, en el relato, falta saber que es lo que esta todavía lejos de la mejora, antes de apresurarnos a decir si esta bien o mal o si se refiere a algo que aún no ha aparecido. Algunos autores gustan de alargar demasiado sus descripciones y pensamientos convirtiéndose en ocasiones en inacabables y a veces es difícil seguirles el hilo, pues en este caso la idea parece inacabada. Gracias.

Comment: Without a citation to where you found it this is going to be hard to answer as @Diego has already outlined.

Comment: A very tricky sentence, indeed. Not sure it is correct

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a mistake in the wording, the correct way to make it an understandable sentence is:

> Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren **al verse** todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios...

<sub>*All this large area of the country is in a clear second category in terms of transport possibilities by train, as it is still far from improving frequencies or prices...*</sub>

**Al verse** --> To see itself

---

Or by removing **"de"** before *-la mejora de frecuencias-*:

> Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren al ver todavía lejos la mejora de frecuencias o precios...

<sub>*All this large area of the country is in a clear second category in possibilities of transport by train, seeing the improvement of frequencies or prices still far away...*</sub>

Comment: And it should also be "toda esta gran área"...

Comment: I'm not sure the action "ver" can attach to inanimate "área".

Answer (score 1):

The text has three main problems:

1. The masculine form of "área".
2. "Ver" and "reflejar" should be both pronominal.
3. "Reflejar" should be in the singular (its subject is "mejora").

Original text:

Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren al ver todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios que en muchos casos están reflejando gracias a la llegada de las nuevas marcas a varias rutas como...

Revised text:

**Toda esta** gran área del país está en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren al ver**se** todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios que en muchos casos **se** **está** reflejando/**está** reflejándo**se** gracias a la llegada de las nuevas marcas a varias rutas como...

"Verse", like "encontrarse" or "hallarse", is an elegant way of replacing the copula:

- Toda esta gran área del país está / **se ve** / **se encuentra** / **se halla** todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios...

Also, intransitive "reflejar" needs to be pronominal. Otherwise, it is transitive:

- La mejora de frecuencias está reflejando la llegada de nuevas marcas (the increased frequency evidences the arrival of new trademarks)
- La mejora de frecuencias se está reflejando por/gracias a la llegada de nuevas marcas (the increased frequency becomes evident due to the arrival of new trademarks)

Answer (score 1):

The excerpt you cite is very problematic:

- "al ver", as other answers have pointed out, is not correctly used and should be passive
- There are several nested sentences without any punctuation marks
- There are typos
  :

> Tod**a** est**a** gran área del país est**á** en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tre**n,** al ver**se** todavía lejos la mejora de frecuencias o precio**s,** que en muchos casos **se** están reflejando gracias a la llegada de las nuevas marcas a varias ruta**s,** como...

Feeding this to Google Translate gives:

> All this large area of ​​the country is in a clear second category in terms of transport possibilities by train, as improvements in frequencies or prices are still far away, which in many cases are being reflected thanks to the arrival of new brands on various routes, such as ...

Answer (score 0):

*Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren al ver todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios...*

- Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren, al **encontrar-la**(toda este gran área del país) todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios...
- **ver-la** = (encontrar-la, hallar-la) = (el gran área del país). "de transporte de tren, al hallar**la** (encontrar**la** toda este gran área del país), todavía lejos de la mejora...

*Todo este gran área del país esta en una clara segunda categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren al **ver-la hallada (o encontrarla)** todavía lejos de la mejora de frecuencias o precios...*

- **...posibilidades de transporte por tren, al ver u observar que se encuentra o halla todavía lejos**...

---

Otra posibilidad

"**Toda** **esta** gran área del país está en una clara categoría en posibilidades de transporte por tren, **al ver todavía lejos las mejoras** de frecuencias o precios que en muchos casos están reflejando**se**, gracias a la llegada de las nuevas marcas a varias rutas como.. ."

---

**P.D.** Necesitaría leer el párrafo completo, pues quizás dentro de aquel contexto completo, casi todo este bien escrito y solo hagan falta poner algunas comas, que parecen estar desaparecidas.

Comment: As wimi correctly pointed out, "área" is feminine.

Comment: Hola Gustavson, espero te encuentres bien. Ya lo vi, pero le otorgue el beneficio de la duda, ya que quizás el escritor entendiese que "Área" al ser un sustantivo femenino que empieza por "a" tónica, cuando va precedido de un artículo determinado singular, lo adecuado es emplear la forma "el", "el área", y no "la área". Imagino que entendería "este" con igual forma masculina, "este área" o "este gran área". Quizás me encuentre simplemente en un error, pero en ese momento me asalto la duda. Gracias

Comment: La regla que mencionas respecto de sustantivos femeninos que comienzan con "a" acentuada solo aplica a los artículos, no a los demostrativos. Se dice: EL ÁREA, UN ÁREA, pero ESTA ÁREA, ESA ÁREA, AQUELLA ÁREA

Comment: Manual de español urgente, de la AGENCIA EFE: «Es bien sabido que se emplea el y un ante nombre femenino que empieza por a- o ha- tónicas: el habla, un águila. Pero esta anómala concordancia no debe producirse en el caso de los adjetivos (una agria polémica, la árida llanura), ni cuando entre el artículo y el nombre que empieza por a- o ha- se introduce un adjetivo (la incomprensible habla, una altiva águila). Esa misma posibilidad se produce con algún, ningún. Pero no con otro  ni con todo  (otra ave, toda África) ni con los demostrativos. Escríbase pues esta ave, esa ave, aquella ave.» p.47

Comment: Gracias Gustavson por las aclaraciones.